# Py2Exe: missing module errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I have written a `py` script that uses `Selenium`, `XmltoDict` and `BeautifulSoup`, I am getting following errors on running commands. How do I include them?

```
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'builder.ParserRejected
Markup', 'builder.builder_registry', 'cchardet', 'chardet', 'defusedexpat', 'htm
l.parser', 'html5lib', 'html5lib.constants', 'http.client', 'iconv_codec', 'lxml
', 'ordereddict', 'urllib.parse', 'win32pipe', 'winreg']['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'builder.ParserRejected
Markup', 'builder.builder_registry', 'cchardet', 'chardet', 'defusedexpat', 'htm
l.parser', 'html5lib', 'html5lib.constants', 'http.client', 'iconv_codec', 'lxml
', 'ordereddict', 'urllib.parse', 'win32pipe', 'winreg']
```

I am using Py27

Answer (score 0):

There a variety of reasons why py2exe will miss packages that you need and include packages that you don't need.  Using the [py2exe setup options](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) you can help it out.

In your setup for py2exe:

```
py2exe_options = {
    ...
    packages=['Selenium', 'XmltoDict', 'BeautifulSoup'],  # additional packages
    includes=[], # additional modules
    excludes=[], # exluded modules
    ...
}
setup(...,
      options = {
          ... 
          'py2exe': py2exe_options,
          ...
      },
      ...
)
```